# Django/NGINX/Gunicorn/Ubuntu: Media files - [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I've deployed my web on Digital Ocean VPS - Ubuntu 14.04. I have a `ImageField` in one of my models which I choose in Django admin (browse pc and upload the image). The problem is that this image can't be saved into `/media/categories/`. It's raising:

> [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/home/django/project/media/categories/television_d3q3EM0.png'

I thought that it is, because Nginx hasn't write privileges to `/media/` directory so I run these commands:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /media/
```

which didn't help

```
sudo chown -R django /media/
```

which didn't help neither

I'm a newbie in Linux rights so I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Media folder is in `/project/` directory (where the `manage.py` is).

Here are permissions of the `/media/` folder.

Owner has rights so I don't know why `sudo chown -R www-data /media/` didn't work.

[image]

**GUNICORN OWNER**

```
 ps aux | grep gunicorn
django   16636  0.3  2.7  66040 13616 ?        Ss   08:16   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn --name=project --pythonpath=project --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py project.wsgi:application
django   16642  1.1  7.8 174800 39164 ?        S    08:16   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn --name=project --pythonpath=project --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py project.wsgi:application
django   16643  1.9 10.5 214244 52808 ?        S    08:16   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn --name=project --pythonpath=project --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py project.wsgi:application
django   16644  2.3 10.4 209232 52224 ?        S    08:16   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/gunicorn --name=project --pythonpath=project --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py project.wsgi:application
root     16667  0.0  0.1  11744   932 pts/0    S+   08:17   0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249115/errno-13-permission-denied-using-gunicorn

Comment: Your folder permissions should be `755` not `311`.

Comment: @themanatuf It didn't help. I tried to change it.

Comment: maybe `sudo chown -R yourusername:www-data /home/django/project/media`

Answer (score 3):

The problem was with `chown` command.

```
sudo chown -R django /media/
```

worked because there is /media/ directory - it is an absolute path to the `media` folder at the bottom of the tree.

I should instead do:

`sudo chown -R django media/` which is a relative path (I was in project directory).

The `django` user is handling `gunicorn` so `django` has to be `media/` owner (or has to have appropriate rights).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using gunicorn, make sure the user which is running gunicorn have permissions to write to the specified path.  Check out [gunicorn deployment docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#systemd) to see how to control which user is running gunicorn.

Comment: He's using nginx, says so in the original post.

Comment: So your answer was partially correct. The problem was specifying path. I should do media/ instead of /media/.