# Gunicorn debugging permission denied for sock file

Tags: linux, gunicorn

I believe there's an issue with my gunicorn sock file if I start/stop gunicorn the sock file is created and deleted and the status of gunicorn is active and running okay but when I try to load the site I get a 502 gateway error and a permission denied for the sock file.

```
2017/07/20 10:06:29 [crit] 25878#25878: *2189 connect() to unix:/home/sammy/revamp/revamp.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 196.103.90.57, server: plusc...
```

Here's the sock file's permissions

```
srwxrwxrwx  1 sammy    www-data       0 Jul 20 10:10 revamp.sock=
```

and the gunicorn settings

```
    [Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/revamp
ExecStart=/home/sammy/revamp/revampenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/sammy/revamp/revamp.sock revamp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the current username is `sammy`

Comment: (Have you checked the "use pathname permissions" ("x"-bits) on the directories involved?)

Comment: (Note [Errno 13 Permission denied using Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28249115) in the "related" column.)

Answer (score 2):

This fixed the issue I made `sudo chown -R sammy:www-data revamp` I set the parent folder to the same group and user as the gunicorn conf